# Counting the number of times a time series crosses an upper and lower band in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have a `df` looking like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Upper': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
                   'Lower': [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
                   'X': [0,1,1.5,1,0.5,1,1.5,1,0,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-1,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-1,0]})
```

Which gives us the resulting chart:
[image]

What I need to do is count the number of times the red line `X` breaches either the `Upper` or `Lower` line AND then breaches the opposite line. In the example above the count would simply be 1.

What I'm thinking is maybe creating a column that records what the most recent line breached was and then count the number of times in the time series the lines switch.

This would look something like this:

```
    Upper  Lower    X Breach
0       1     -1  0.0    NaN
1       1     -1  1.0    NaN
2       1     -1  1.5  Upper
3       1     -1  1.0  Upper
4       1     -1  0.5  Upper
5       1     -1  1.0  Upper
6       1     -1  1.5  Upper
7       1     -1  1.0  Upper
8       1     -1  0.0  Upper
9       1     -1 -0.5  Upper
10      1     -1 -1.0  Upper
11      1     -1 -1.5  Lower
12      1     -1 -1.0  Lower
13      1     -1 -0.5  Lower
14      1     -1 -1.0  Lower
15      1     -1 -1.5  Lower
16      1     -1 -1.0  Lower
17      1     -1  0.0  Lower
```

As you can see at index position 10 and 11 we change from `Upper` to `Lower`, I would then count this as 1.

I don't really know how I would go about achieving this however? My real time series is large, and there are a number of these time series I need to do these calculations on.

Any help would be really appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two Series, one that checks whether we are above the upper bound and another that checks whether you are below the lower bound. Then by grouping the upper by the lower, you can determine where you are above/below the Upper bound and then switch to being above or below the opposite bound.

We need to manually clean up the edges. The last point always gets incorrectly flagged since `shift` gives it a `NaN`, so we remove it. And for the left edge we check if it was ever below the lower bound before it crosses the upper and either keep or remove the first index accordingly.

(I added a few lines to illustrate how this would work for multiple different cases).

#### Sample

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0,1,1.5,1,0.5,1,1.5,1,0,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-1,
                         -0.5,-1,-1.5,-1,0,0.75,1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1, -1,-1.5, -0.5, 
                         0, -1.5, 0, 0.25, -1.5, -1, 0.25,0.75, 1.25, 0.75, 
                         0.5, 1.7, 0.5, 1.1, 0.25, -0.5, -1.1, -0.9, -1.4]})
df['Upper'] = 1
df['Lower'] = -1
```

---

#### Code

```
up = df['X'].gt(df['Upper'])
low = df['X'].lt(df['Lower'])
up = up.groupby(low.cumsum()).cummax()

# Determine where switches occur, last is always dropped
indices = up[up.ne(up.shift(-1))].index[:-1]  
#Int64Index([1, 10, 18, 24, 34, 42], dtype='int64')

# Check if we need to remove the first point
init = df[~up.cummax()]
if not any(init['X'].lt(init['Lower'])):
    indices = indices[1:]

# This correctly flags the last index before the switch
print(indices)
#Int64Index([10, 18, 24, 34, 42], dtype='int64')
```

---

#### Illustration of results

Vertical lines are plotted at the index values I've flagged above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df['X'].plot(ax=ax, marker='o')
ax.axhline(1, 0, 1, color='red')
ax.axhline(-1, 0, 1, color='red')

for index in indices:
    ax.axvline(index, 0, 1, color='grey', linestyle='--')
```

[image]